# Find mean of entries in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas data frame as below-

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'key':['X','X','Y','Y','Z'], 'X':np.arange(5), 'Y': [3,4,5,6,7]})
```

I want to derive mean for the columns 'X' and 'Y', grouped according to the column 'key'

tried this-

```
df = df[['X','Y']].mean(axis=1) #but unable to group by 'key'
```

expected output-

```
key   X    Y
X    1.1  1.1
Y    2.2  2.2
Z    3.3  3.3
```

Comment: Do you need `df.groupby('key', as_index=False).mean()` ?

Comment: yes, groupby 'key' @jezrael